# The existence of adjoint operator for Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}(S^2, \mathbb R^n)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sg.symplectic-geometry, vector-bundles, sobolev-spaces

It is known that if $D:H_1 \to H_2$ is a bounded operator between Hilbert spaces, then there exists an adjoint operator $D^* : H_2 \to H_1$ (the field is just $\mathbb R$ rather than $\mathbb C$, so we can identify $H^*$ with $H$) such that 
$$
\langle Dx,y \rangle_{H_2}=\langle x,D^*y\rangle_{H_1}
$$

Nevertheless, let us think a more complicated case as follows.

Let $p>2$ and then $X=W^{1,p}(S^2, \mathbb R^n)$ is a Banach space. We define
$$
\langle f,g\rangle:= \int_{S^2} \langle f(x),g(x) \rangle_{\mathbb R^n} d\mathrm{vol}_{S^2}(x)
$$for $f,g\in X$.
By Sobolev embedding we know functions in $X$ are continuous. Thus, this bilinear pairing is positive (i.e.$\langle f,f\rangle =0$ implies $f =0$ ) and becomes an inner product.

**Question 1**: Is the topology on $X$ induced by this inner product "compatible" with the original $W^{1,p}$-topology on $X$ in some sense?

**Question 2**: If there is a bounded linear operator $D: X\to X$, then can we define an adjoint operator $D^*: X\to X$ using this inner product? For example, a possibility is that for $f\in X$ we can "define" $D^*f$ pointwisely by $\langle Dg(x), f(x)\rangle_{\mathbb R^n}= \langle g(x), D^*f(x)\rangle_{\mathbb R^n}$

**Quesition 3**: By the way, the purpose of this question is to understand the adjoint operator $D_u^*$ defined in McDuff-Salamon's book J-holomorphic curves and symplectic topology, 2nd edition (cf. page 48 or page 582). Briefly, let $E$ and $F$ be vector bundles over $S^2$, and let $D$ be an operator
$$
D: W^{l,p}(S^2, E) \to W^{l-1,p}(S^2, F)
$$
then how to see that the formal adjoint will be an operator
$$
D^*: W^{l,p}(S^2, F) \to W^{l-1,p}(S^2,E)
$$? Why not an operator from $W^{l-1,p}(S^2, F)$ to $W^{l,p}(S^2,E)$?

Comment: Your inner product is just the $L^2$ inner product, isn't it?  So you are looking at the $L^2$ topology on $X$.  It's strictly weaker than the $W^{1,p}$ topology.  In particular, this inner product is incomplete on $X$, so the Riesz representation theorem won't hold, and your plan for defining the adjoint is flawed.

Comment: You'd have the same problem if you included weak derivatives up to order $k$ in there, you'd get $W^{k,2}$ instead of $W^{k,p}$ which would be weaker since the domain is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Question 3, let us consider the simpler situation $D = \partial_\theta$ as an operator
$$ \partial_\theta : W^{k,p}(S^1,\mathbb R) \to W^{k-1,p}(S^1,\mathbb R)\,.$$
The adjoint is an operator
$$ \partial_\theta^\ast : W^{-k+1,q}(S^1,\mathbb R) \to W^{-k,q}(S^1,\mathbb R)\,,$$
with $\frac 1p + \frac 1q = 1$. However, a direct calculation using integration by parts will show you that for $f \in W^{k,p}(S^1,\mathbb R)$ one has
$$ \partial_\theta^\ast f = -\partial_\theta f\,. $$

Similarly, I would expect that the mapping properties of the operator $D^\ast$ you encountered are due to the specific nature of the operator $D$ rather than a general result from functional analysis.